# set content range in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have many resting api in my spring boot application.

```
@GetMapping("lc/all")
    List<LC> getAll()
    {
        return lcRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Mainly they are sending list.

Now for some reason, I have to receive the length of the response. Changing for each and every method would be tedious.

How can I set `Content-Range` for each method automatically.

I have modified the CORS:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                        .exposedHeaders("Content-Range");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a filter that writes only the requested range part as a response when range header is present.

```
package com.example.contentrange;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT;
import static javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.http.HttpRange;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;

@WebFilter("/*")
public class AddResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    var rangeHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Range");

    // if there is no range request in the header than do the "normal" filtering
    if (rangeHeader == null) {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
      return;
    }

    HttpRange range = HttpRange.parseRanges(rangeHeader).get(0);

    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper =
        new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

    try {
      chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    } finally {
      byte[] copy = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
      int size = responseWrapper.getContentSize();
      int lower = (int) range.getRangeStart(size);
      int upper = (int) range.getRangeEnd(size);
      if (lower <= size) {
        responseWrapper.setStatus(SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
        byte[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(copy, lower, upper + 1);
        String newContent = new String(subArray, UTF_8);
        responseWrapper.reset();
        responseWrapper.setHeader(
            "Content-Range", String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", lower, upper, size));
        responseWrapper.setContentLength(newContent.length());
        responseWrapper.getWriter().write(newContent);
        responseWrapper.getWriter().flush();
        responseWrapper.flushBuffer();
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
      } else {
        responseWrapper.setStatus(SC_REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second you need to add org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan annotation to your application class.

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class ContentRangeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContentRangeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

For more info on Range: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: not working... not working with front end, I even tried postman `Content-Type,Transfer-Encoding,Date` only these 3 headers are present in response.. no content range.. do i need to bring any change my rest api s ??

Comment: Do you send in Range header in the request as well as it is required to have Content-range in the response. see: [4. Responses to a Range Request](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4) and [4.2. Content-Range](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4.2)

Comment: actually i'm using react-admin... so it should, i guess... cause it is giving me this error : content-range not found...

Comment: I uploaded a quick solution and how I tested it to [github](https://github.com/blzsaa/contentRange). There are examples on how to call it in README and ContentRangeApplicationTests

Comment: as your solution actually does solve the content-range problem, i have upvoted the answer, but i can't accept, as it is not working with my front-end

Comment: thanks, i figured the front-end somehow, took more a while

Comment: @Danial, can you share how you fixed this?

Comment: @letimome this is accepted answer, this worked... **but later I moved onto paged repository**.. other approach i tried is intercepting in front-end and modify those contents